# making clones of an html file

Tags: php, batch-file

If I have a file called file.html how do i make 10 clones of this file via PHP such that they are renamed file1....file10?

This code makes the files but they are all blank when they should be duplicates of mypage.html (which is less than 1kb)

```
<?php


$text = file_get_contents('mypage.html');
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    file_put_contents('file'.$i.'.html', $data);
}




?>
```

If I have a file called file.html how do i make 10 clones of this file via PHP such that they are renamed file1....file10?

This code makes the files but they are all blank when they should be duplicates of mypage.html (which is less than 1kb)

Comment: I am just curious: For what purpose do you want to clone your php file?

Comment: He does not want to clone the PHP file, `mypage.html` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your variable names:

> ***$text*** = file_get_contents('mypage.html');
>
> for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
>
> file_put_contents('file'.$i.'.html', ***$data***);
>
> }

Answer (score 2):

You meant `$text`, and `10` not `100` right ? Also make sure you have permission to write where you want those files.

```
$text = file_get_contents('mypage.html');
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    file_put_contents('file'.$i.'.html', $text);
}
```

It's best to specify a `dump` folder

```
$text = file_get_contents('mypage.html');
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    file_put_contents('cloned/file'.$i.'.html', $text);
}
```

In `cloned` folder your `PHP` script must have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

why not use php copy function?
[php copy manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
    <?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

HOw about just use the `copy()` function in a loop instead of worrying about the contents of the file?

```
$filename = 'mypage.html';
for ($i=1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    copy($filename, 'file'.$i.'html');
}
```

Note the use of `$i=1` and `$i<11` in loop this would give values of 1-10 instead of 0-9.